# Find how many shares of a horse a user has? (Postgresql query)

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, psql

I have four tables: users, orders, shares, and horses.

One user has many orders, one order has many shares, and one horse has many shares.

I want to find how many shares of each horse does a specific user owns (including when a user owns zero shares in a particular horse).

I have tried the following, however I cannot retrieve the cases when a user owns zero shares for a particular horse.

```
$userHorses = DB::table('orders')->join('shares', 'orders.id', '=', 'shares.order_id')
          ->join('horses', 'horses.id', '=', 'shares.horse_id')
          ->where('orders.user_id',$user_id)
          ->select('horses.name','horses.id','horses.slug',DB::raw('count(*) as totalShares'))
          ->groupBy('horses.name','horses.id','horses.slug')
          ->get();

return $userHorses;
```

Comment: Here is your problem visualized: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all horses with user share count you will need left join with conditional aggregation like

```
$userHorses = DB::table('horses h')
          ->leftJoin('shares s', 'h.id', '=', 's.horse_id')
          ->leftJoin('orders o', 'o.id', '=', 's.order_id')
          ->select('h.name',
            'h.id',
            'h.slug',
            DB::raw('sum(case when o.user_id = :user_id then 1 else 0 end) as totalShares', ['user_id' => $user_id])
          )
          ->groupBy('h.name','h.id','h.slug')
          ->get();
```

Comment: This approach for some reason is not taking into consideration the where clause for a specific user. It is returning the total shares of all users.

Comment: Yes you were correct about forgetting the use keyword, but still I am not getting the desired results.

Comment: only for a specific user

Comment: @PetroBianka I have updated my answer it should give you desired results

Comment: No, it still retrieves only the records where the user has shares. It does not return the records where the user does not have any share for a horse.

Comment: @PetroBianka see the updated version with conditional aggregation, hope it works this time

Comment: That seems to be the right query because I am getting the desired result. The only thing that is missing is for some reasons I cannot pass the variable user_id inside the DB:raw. I am getting  the following error : "bind message supplies 0 parameters".

Comment: I came with a work around. I just passed the variable between two single quotes.

Comment: Direct variable manipulation in query is a bad paractice, If you can find a way around binding parameters it would be good